# Liquibase Gradle Plugin: Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown option: 'log-level'

Tags: gradle, liquibase

I have problems when upgrading from org.liquibase.gradle version 2.1.1 to 2.2.0.
I both cases I use org.liquibase:liquibase-core:4.23.1. With Gradle plugin version 2.1.1
version everything works fine (so stick to that version) but on 2.2.0 I got the error:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Unknown option: 'log-level'
For more information, please use the --logLevel flag
```

When I debug the command that is created by the Liquibase Gradle Plugin then I can see:

```
...  --log-level=info ... --output-file=NotNeeded --changelog-file=src/main/resources/liquibase/changeLog-master.xml ...
```

And in the Liquibase documentation says that

```
--log-level=INFO
```

is fine. So what is the problem here? Has someone more more information?

Thanks!

Comment: I started receiving the same error when upgrading the org.liquibase:liquibase-core dependency from 4.23.1 to 4.23.2.

Comment: I have to correct myself regarding my last comment. The issue seems not to be within the liquibase-core dependency. For me the error also starts occurring when upgrading the liquibase gradle plugin from version 2.1.1 to 2.2.0.